# Does Bonding mode 0 works on Cisco SG100 and achieve 2GB speed for NFS?

Tags: networking, nfs, switch, server-message-block, bonding

I am planing to buy a switcher to link 2 servers each with 2 NICs (Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection).

I read that "balance-rr is the only mode were one single TCP connection can actually reach 2 Gb/s" in [Does linux balance-rr (bond mode=0) work with all switches?](https://serverfault.com/questions/341702/does-linux-balance-rr-bond-mode-0-work-with-all-switches) . And it also says "actually balance-rr and balance-xor works just fine without any further switch configuration on any other switches than Cisco".

So, will Cisco `SG100` work for `balance-rr` or I have to choose either `SG200` or other **Unmanaged Switches** like D-link `DGS-1024T` ?

I think NFS should use 1 connections for each file request, so even if I choose other bonding modes(2,4,5,6), in reality the speed will still faster than 1GB/s when I `cp` files between 2 Servers. Is this right ?

Also, I wonder whether `Samba` will suffered for windows clients as that post says "CIFS doesn't play well with balance-rr".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cisco SG100 switch is an unmanaged switch so will behave just the same as any other unmanaged switch. Most Cisco switches are managed.

Looking at the [Linux foundation](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/bonding#Which_switches.2Fsystems_does_it_work_with.3F) website you will need a switch which supports etherchannel

> In the basic balance modes (balance-rr and balance-xor), it works with
>   any system that supports etherchannel (also called trunking). Most
>   managed switches currently available have such support, and many
>   unmanaged switches as well.

Comment: Would you show me some examples for "many unmanaged switches as well" that supports etherchannel/trunking ? I googled and found none.

Comment: I am not aware of any myself as I have always done etherchannel on managed Cisco switches

Comment: `Cisco SG200` supports "Port grouping" (LACP), does this mean it support `balance-rr` ? http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/switches/ps5718/ps11229/data_sheet_c78-634369.html

Comment: That should work, you would need to enable port grouping on the ports the server is plugged in to